# Can anybody help me to correct the following code?

Tags: java

Please help me to identify my mistakes in this code. I am new to Java. Excuse me if I have done any mistake. This is one of codingbat java questions. I am getting Timed Out error message for some inputs like "xxxyakyyyakzzz". For some inputs like "yakpak" and "pakyak" this code is working fine.

Question:
Suppose the string "yak" is unlucky. Given a string, return a version where all the  "yak" are removed, but the "a" can be any char. The "yak" strings will not overlap.

```
 public String stringYak(String str) {
                String result = "";
                int yakIndex = str.indexOf("yak");
                if (yakIndex == -1) 
                    return str; //there is no yak
                //there is at least one yak
                //if there are yaks store their indexes in the arraylist
                ArrayList<Integer> yakArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                int length = str.length();
                yakIndex = 0;
                while (yakIndex < length - 3) {
                    yakIndex = str.indexOf("yak", yakIndex);
                    yakArray.add(yakIndex);
                    yakIndex += 3;
                }//all the yak indexes are stored in the arraylist
                //iterate through the arraylist. skip the yaks and get non-yak substrings
                for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (yakArray.contains(i)) 
                        i = i + 2;
                    else 
                        result = result + str.charAt(i);
                }
                return result;
 }
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Share the input you gave and expected and actual output. That way you might get better help.

Comment: Why you don't use replaceAll to remove all `yak`?

Comment: what you get from above code error or exception please display it.

Comment: Your code appears not to take the "a can be any char" part into account. That's still easy to fix using `String.replaceAll` which takes a regex pattern...

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there any meaning for that 'a can be any char' part. It just means that "yak" can be anywhere in the string. Excuse me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Phoenix: I suspect it actually means you're trying to replace "yak", "ybk", "yck", "ydk" etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks again. But can you correct the code considering that only "yak" are to be removed. String replaceAll() is a good solution. But, for the sake of learning I want the existing code to be corrected. I used ArrayList. Is it wrong using it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be looking for any three character sequence starting with a 'y' and ending with a 'k'? Like so?

```
public static String stringYak(String str) {
  char[] chars = (str != null) ? str.toCharArray()
      : new char[] {};
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == 'y' && chars[i + 2] == 'k') { // if we have 'y' and two away is 'k'
                                                  // then it's unlucky...
      i += 2;
      continue; //skip the statement sb.append 
    }           //do not append any pattern like y1k or yak etc
    sb.append(chars[i]);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(stringYak("1yik2yak3yuk4")); // Remove the "unlucky" strings
                                                  // The result will be 1234.
}
```

Comment: "a" can be every character, you said

Comment: What does "a" can be any char mean then?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for your solution. I understood the question properly now. But can you correct my code considering that only "yak"s are to be removed.

Comment: Instead of `if (chars[i] == 'y' && chars[i + 2] == 'k')` try `if (chars[i] == 'y' && chars[i+1] == 'a' && chars[i + 2] == 'k')`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your programming assignment. You need to use regular expressions.

Look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex for more information.
Remember, that you can not use contains. Your code maybe something like

```
result = str.removeall("y\wk")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public static String stringYak(String str) {

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='y'){
            str=str.replace("yak", "");
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.